# Aligning .Xauthority between GDM and SSH

Tags: ssh, x11-forwarding, emacsclient, gdm, emacs-server

I've run into a problem in that if I start Emacs in daemon mode on my remote system, then in my local system I run `ssh remotehost emacsclient -c`, it fails with *X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.*  However, things like `ssh remotehost xterm` work fine, so it's nothing to do with ssh connections, X forwarding, etc.

Both systems in question are running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

The problem, as could be guessed, is xauth and in particular after much reading of issues filed back in 2010/2011, it seems to be due to the way GDM sets the `XAUTHORITY` environment variable to `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/gdm/Xauthority` (something like `/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority`), while incoming SSH connections do **not** set `XAUTHORITY` before the set up xauth cookies for the SSH session.

This means that ssh xauth cookies are added in the default `$HOME/.Xauthority` file.  My Emacs daemon cannot see these cookies because it's using the GDM `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/gdm/Xauthority` file.

As I've said it seems like this disparity has been a known issue for 8+ years... has no one resolved it?  Crazy.  I have written a script that installs the cookie but having to do so is pretty gross.

Is there a way to get my ssh session to use the GDM Xauthority file?  I've tried setting `XAUTHORITY` in my shell setup but apparently that is set too late, after the SSH daemon configures the new Xauth cookie, because it's still put into `$HOME/.Xauthority`.

Comment: This blog post seems to have answers: https://blog.allardhendriksen.nl/posts/remote-emacs-on-gnome-using-x/

Comment: I think it's going to be hard to get SSH to put its cookies in the right place, since it seems like modern GDM chooses a fresh path for each session's authority file. For example, mine is `/run/user/1000/.mutter-Xwaylandauth.6WSOI1` at the moment. If there were multiple GDM sessions live at the same time, it wouldn't be clear which one SSH should use.

Answer (score 0):

It's indeed hard to guess where the X file is.  In my case I ended up hacking some shell thing to do it as part of a wrapper around `emacsclient`.  The relevant bits are:

```
fix_xauth() (
  if [[ -z "$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR" ]]; then return; fi
  if [[ ! -e "$HOME/.Xauthority" ]]; then return; fi
  shopt -s nullglob; shopt -u failglob
  for xauth in "$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/"{".mutter-Xwaylandauth"*,"gdm/Xauthority"}; do
    if [[ ! -f "$xauth" ]]; then continue; fi
    xauth -f "$xauth" merge "$HOME/.Xauthority"
  done
)
```